# Distinguish between click on AccessoryView and Cell Content and will Apple allow it?(iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I was wondering if there is a delegate method to implement that let's me distinguish between a tap on the content view of the cell and the disclosure symbol to the right.
I would like to send the user to two different view depending on where on the cell they tap.

I think the event is normally caught by testing if the tableView is:

(self.editing)

I can only remember having seen this functionality during editing in the Alarm Clock and Address Book app. Does anyone know if it is even "allowed" by Apple or is it considered "bad" user interface design? Anyone know of other Apple apps that implements this approach?

Hope someone can shed a little light on this issue:)
Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Implement the Delegate method to handle taps on accessory button

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

And you know how to handle cell selection..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Thank you Prakash:)

Still hope to hear if anyone has experience or even just an opinion on using this approach.

Comment: One search on google led me here, gave me exactly what i wanted! +1