# Unable to use the tableview cell.accessoryView for Click event

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi for this great community. I just need to implement a simple delete functionality in tableView. I know that this can be implemented using swipe delete (table view delegate). But the client needs something like this:

[image: reference_image]

I have done this design using  `cell.accessoryView = trash_icon;`.  Now the requirement is,

- when I tap the tableView cell. It must show the details of the
  vehicle.
- If I tap the bin/trash icon it must delete that row.

  I have successfully done the navigation to vehicle Details using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the Cells. But stuck at implementing the delete option. The problem is whenever I tap the trash icon, it goes to vehicle details page. I have looked upon the followings [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754797/distinguish-between-click-on-accessoryview-and-cell-content-and-will-apple-allow)  ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146949/uitableviewcell-accessoryview-overlap-custom-button-of-cell-or-how-to-change-acc) ,[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388812/add-button-to-uitableviewcells-accessory-view) and more but I'm not able to get the idea for implementing this. Also I tried the `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` by specifying the cell as `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`, 
  `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`
  It works but the problem is I'm not able to change the default image of the accessoryType. Please guide me and thanks for reading this patiently!

**EDIT:** What I have tried upto now is:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 

cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
//    cell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x717579);
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:NSLocalizedString(@"font_name",nil) size:13];
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIImageView *trash_icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_vehicle_delete.png"]];
if(indexPath.section != [vehicleDetails count]) {
    //cell.accessoryView = trash_icon;  --> If I keep this only Image appears but the action doesn't gets triggered
} else {
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellStyleDefault
}

if(indexPath.section == [vehicleDetails count])
{
    addnewLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:NSLocalizedString(@"font_name",nil) size:13];
    addnewLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    addnewLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    addnewLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"vehicle_new",nil);
    [cell addSubview:addnewLabel];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"input-plus.png"]]autorelease];
    background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 35);
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
        background.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35);
    
    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 300, 35)]autorelease];
    [cell.backgroundView addSubview:background];
}else
{
    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vehicle #%li: %@",indexPath.section+1,[[vehicleDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"make"]];
    UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text field 2x.png"]]autorelease];
    background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 35);
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
        background.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 35);
    
    
    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 300, 35)]autorelease];
    [cell.backgroundView addSubview:background];
}

return cell;
}
```

The above method successfully calls the

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{
//here I do the delete stuff
```

But the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: edited bro. posted the code which I've tried and the output of it.!

Comment: Best approach is probably to create a button for the custom `accessoryView` and give it a target method (just like any other button).

Comment: @DonMag is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Finally I got the solution by adding the custom button to the accessory view and added the selector for that, there by handling the delete functionality

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        ...
        ...

        if(indexPath.section != [vehicleDetails count]) {
        //Adding the custom button to the accessory view
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(275, 140, 30, 30);
            [button setImage: trash_icon.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            //Adding the selector for the Button
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(vehicleDeleteHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            button.tag = indexPath.section;
            cell.accessoryView  = button;
        }
        ...
        ...
}

//Defining the selector function for the button.
-(void)vehicleDeleteHandler: (id)sender {
//    if([sender tag] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[sender tag]);
    //Delete Functionality
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the delegation design pattern

> STEP-I : Make the protocol to delegate with cell

This protocol you will be confirmed in the UIViewController Class and contain two methods

- **cellDidTaaped**: method called when cell did tap
- **accessoryViewDidTapped** : method called when accessoryView did tap

  ```
  protocol ItemCellDelegate :class{
      func cellDidTaaped(withCell cell:ItemCell)
      func accessoryViewDidTapped(withCell cell:ItemCell, state :Bool)
  }
  ```

> STEP-II : Make the UITableViewCell class to customize the accessory view

- initialize the accessoryView with UiimageView
- We will make two UITapGestureRecognizer when every one recognize, the delegate 
  method of it will be fired

**Note**: we define a bool Flag to send it by the protocol to determine the sate of accessoryView if it needed to change the image of it

```
class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var  delegte:ItemCellDelegate?

private var accessoryViewTappedFlag = false


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    let cellGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ItemCell.cellViewDidTapped))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(cellGestureRecognizer)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.accessoryView = imageView
    (self.accessoryView as! UIImageView).image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Birthdays")

    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ItemCell.accessoryViewDidTapped))
    accessoryView!.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

func accessoryViewDidTapped() {
    self.accessoryViewTappedFlag = !accessoryViewTappedFlag
    delegte?.accessoryViewDidTapped(withCell: self, state: accessoryViewTappedFlag)
}
func cellViewDidTapped() {
    delegte?.cellDidTaaped(withCell: self)
}

}
```

> STEP-III : Make UIViewControler the delegate of call

we must confirm the delegate of the cell when tableView call cellForRowAt
function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
    cell.delegte =  self
    ....
    return cell
}
```

> STEP-IV : Confirm the delegate of cell at UIViewControler class

Confirm the ItemCellDelegate on listItemsVC(UIViewControler) and implement the methods

```
extension listItemsVC:ItemCellDelegate{

    func cellDidTaaped(withCell cell: ItemCell) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    //.....
    }
    func accessoryViewDidTaaped(withCell cell: ItemCell, state: Bool) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        if let accessoryView  = cell.accessoryView as? UIImageView {
            if state{
                accessoryView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Trips")
            }else{
                accessoryView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Folder")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** now no need for didSelectRowAt method

Comment: Thanks bro. But I require the solution in Objective C. However I got the solution. I appreciate your effort.!!